# How can I see what IP address my android phone has?

Tags: networking, internet

I would like to know what IP-address my Android phone has. E.g. if I use my phone over WiFi, how can I get the local IP-address that is assigned to my phone?

Comment: The4G-IP can be found under Settings->System->About Phone->IP address

Comment: On My fairly stock Android 11 I can see it under Settings-> About Phone

Answer (score 123, accepted):

The easy way is to go to your WiFi Settings, and hit `Menu > Advanced`. It'll show up there, or you can set it to a static IP if you want.

The cool way is to dial `*#*#4636#*#*` to open the Testing menu. Then click WiFi information, then WiFi Status.

Comment: When I call `##4636##` I get this message: `Connection problem or invalid MMI code`. And in the WiFi Settings advanced menu, I can not see the IP-address if it is set by DHCP. But thanks for that menu, I didn't know about it.

Comment: Haha, sorry about that, yeah apparently an asterisk resolves to an italic pound sign? So you can't actually see your DHCP address in your WiFi Settings? I'm running Cyanogenmod and I can see mine towards the bottom of the menu. Didn't know that wasn't a standard feature. :O

Comment: No, there is no IP-address there on my Nexus One with Android 2.2. but the `Testing meny` was very good.

Answer (score 13):

**`ifconfig` and `ip` Android 7**

```
adb shell ifconfig
adb shell ip address show
```

`ifconfig` was an annoying implementation that did not show all versions by default on earlier versions as explained below, but now it works fine.

**netcfg Android 5.1.1**

This tool was removed in later Android, and `ifconfig` was made more decent and shows all interfaces by default, thus rendering this method useless on newer versions.

```
adb shell netcfg | grep wlan0
```

from your desktop is the best option if you're already developing for Android and have `adb` and an USB connection setup.

Sample output:

```
wlan0 UP 192.168.0.3/24 [...]
```

Confirm with:

```
adb shell ifconfig wlan0
```

`ifconfig` on Android ([home-brewed](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core.git/+/android-5.1.1_r1/toolbox/ifconfig.c)?) is different from the one on desktops (`net-tools` package on Ubuntu 15.10) as it requires the interface to be given.

This is also mentioned at: [Is there a command or application similar to ipconfig?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3715/is-there-a-command-or-application-similar-to-ipconfig)

You could also install a terminal emulator like [Teriminal Emulator from Jack Palevich](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm), open it and type: `netcfg`. But in that case you'd be better off with some app that shows the IPs, since typing on devices is a pain (unless you've got an external keyboard...).

If all you want it so SSH into the device, `adb shell` is the way to go: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34040560/895245

If you are developing a server app, the most user-friendly thing to do would be to show the device's IPs on some `TextView`, which has a pure-Java method: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494465 | https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6064510/how-to-get-ip-address-of-the-device

**Router browser management**

If you are at home, you can:

- connect your desktop to the router with an Ethernet cable
- access some magic vendor dependent address, often http://192.168.0.1
- most vendors have a list of device IPs somewhere in there

**nmap**

If your device is running a server, e.g. SSHD  on port 2222 as explained at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34040560/895245, you can portscan it:

```
sudo nmap -sV --open 192.168.0.0/24 -p2222
```

Comment: Works on Android 4.2.1 as well.

Answer (score 9):

The easiest way is using a tool like e.g. [OS Monitor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.eolwral.osmonitor), which shows you (amongst others) also a lot of network details:

[image: OS Monitor]
<sup>OS Monitor showing network interface details (source: [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.eolwral.osmonitor); click image to enlarge)</sup>

As the screenshot shows, this app reveals for each network interface:

- interface name¹
- IPv4 IP address assigned (if `0.0.0.0`, this interface is currently unused)
- IPv6 address (if available)
- MAC address
- packet statistics (i.e. transfered data)
- a status

¹ interface names might be handled differently on different devices. But in most cases you can tell from the IP where it belongs to. Furthermore, `rmnet` is mostly used for GPRS (mobile data), while WiFi uses names like `tiwlan` or `eth`.

Answer (score 1):

In any terminal emulator app:

```
~$ ip -o a
```

Applicable both to WiFi and Mobile Data. Doesn't require root.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but I think you can try this command:

```
adb shell ip addr show rmnet0  | grep 'inet ' | cut -d ' ' -f 6 | cut -d / -f 1
```

**It  will return your IPV4 assigned by the operator**

> 172.22.1.215

### Note:

Usually, your phone has two networks one by your telcom operator and the other from your wireless interface. These are called network interfaces.

`rmnet0` should be replaced with your interface my case was `rmnet0` usually is `eth0`.

If u want to get the list of interfaces use this command:

```
ip link show
```

You will get something like this:

```
1: lo:  mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0:  mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:ac:6f:65:31:e5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.5/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global eth0
    inet6 fe80::baac:6fff:fe65:31e5/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlan0:  mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:21:6a:ca:9b:10 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: pan0:  mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN 
    link/ether 92:0a:e7:31:e0:83 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: vmnet1:  mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:50:56:c0:00:01 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.121.1/24 brd 192.168.121.255 scope global vmnet1
    inet6 fe80::250:56ff:fec0:1/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6: vmnet8:  mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:50:56:c0:00:08 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.179.1/24 brd 192.168.179.255 scope global vmnet8
    inet6 fe80::250:56ff:fec0:8/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Where usually,

- `lo` – Loopback interface.
- `eth0` – Your first Ethernet network interface on Linux.
- `wlan0` – Wireless network interface in Linux.