# Is there a command or application similar to ipconfig?

Tags: networking, internet, ip-address

I would like to see my network addresses on my phone. On Windows I can use `ipconfig` for this and `ifconfig` on Linux. But how can I see this information on my Android device? Is there an application or command for this?

More specifically I would like to see what IPv4 address I get and what IPv6 address I get or if I don't get one.

Comment: You won't get an IPv6 address, Android doesn't support it: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3718/does-android-have-support-for-ipv6

Comment: @Matthew: I actually get an IPv6 address, but it must be some kind of IPv4toIPv6 or some kind of local address, since it's not the same as when I visit an website. And I can't visit http://ipv6.google.com/

Comment: Ah, my bad.  That must be the "partial support" mentioned on the Google forum.

Comment: @Matthew: There may be something with my network operator too. I actually get a local IPv4 address from them too, it's not the same as I see if I visit an `What is my IP` service. Here is an interesting blog post [T-Mobile: Clever or Insane?](https://blog.wireshark.org/2010/04/t-mobile-clever-or-insane/) but I don't have T-Mobile as network operator.

Answer (score 29):

Android comes with ifconfig, install [Terminal Emulator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm) and type "ifconfig eth0", or use "netcfg" to list all available devices. You need root to use ifconfig though.

Comment: I have tried with `Android Terminal Emulator` but nothing happens if I execute `ifconfig` and if I run `ifconfig eth0` I get `eth0: No such device`. I tested with `netcfg` now and it prints a list with IPv4, but there is no information about IPv6. Thanks anyway.

Comment: The default interface for 3G seems to be named `rmnet0` instead of `eth0` on my Android, so `ifconfig rmnet0` works better.

Comment: you may use "ifconfig wlan0" in your terminal if you have connected with WiFi

Comment: Use `netcfg` to get the list of available devices. Find the short name of the most likely device (it should have the network IP address of your device listed next to it). Then use `ifconfig <shortname>`. For example if `netcfg` shows that `wlan0` has your device's actual network IP address (not bogus IP like `0.0.0.0`), then you should execute `ifconfig wlan0` to get more details.

Comment: @Ziana Mitchell: Thanks for the proposed edit, however I have rejected your proposed edit. Your edit is good information, however you should put it in your own answer rather than editing this one.

Answer (score 7):

just type `netcfg`

it will lists the interface, and work on any terminal emulator. running on the phone itself, or remotely via adb.

Comment: `adb shell netcfg` oh yeah

Comment: No netcfg on my 6.0.1 device, not on busybox either.

Comment: This is no longer on modern android versions.

Answer (score 2):

[NetGenie Lite](http://www.appbrain.com/app/netgenie-lite/com.droidventures.app.NetGenie) can do that.

Comment: I installed it but I find nothing about IPv6. Thanks anyway, it was an interesting app.