# Does Android have support for IPv6?

Tags: networking, internet, ipv6

I wonder if Android has support for IPv6? I have heard that the phone company I use has support for IPv6 and I have a IPv6 address if I visit http://ipv6.whatismyipv6.net.ipv4.sixxs.org/.

But I can not visit IPv6-only sites like http://ipv6.google.com, why is that? Does Android have support for IPv6?

Comment: For a plethora of IPv6 (and IPv4) tools on Android check out my highly rated app. Its been the topmost app for IPv6 since 2011.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tsts.ipv6&hl=en

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As of Android 6.0, the majority of the IPv6 protocol seems to be supported with significant parts missing such as DHCPv6.

Check [Issue #36908577 Support IPv6](https://issuetracker.google.com/36908577) for more info, specifically the issues listed [in comment #105](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36908577#comment105):

> Enhancement: Support for DHCPv6 (RFC 3315) <sup>Won't Fix (Intended behavior)</sup>
> http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=32621
>
> Enhancement: Support for Recursive DNS Server Option in ICMPv6 Router Advertisements (RFC 6106) <sup>Fixed</sup>
> http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=32629
>
> Enhancement: Support connecting to IPv6-only wireless networks <sup>Fixed</sup>
> http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=32630
>
> Defect: APN Protocol ignored when roaming <sup>Fixed</sup>
> http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=32631
>
> Enhancement: Automatic fallback from IPv4/IPv6 APN Protocol to parallel IPv4 + IPv6 <sup>Won't Fix (Obsolete)</sup>
> http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=32632
>
> Defect: Frequently ignores ICMPv6 RAs and other multicast traffic <sup>Won't Fix (Obsolete)</sup>
> http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=32662

<sup>(Consider reading the issues and their comments carefully, because while some of them have their status updated to "fixed", some users were reporting they still have the same issues.)</sup>

Comment: As of android 7.0, issue is still the same.

Answer (score 7):

Updating this question to say that as of Android 4.0, IPv6 is fairly well supported. There are still no visual indicators that it is running/working, but devices pick up IPv6 addresses and try to use them by default.

Comment: "fairly well supported" is quite off. It support obtaining addresses and routes, but has no support for obtaining DNS (either via RA or DHCP), so it's unusable for an average user.

Answer (score 1):

No, as of late 2013, even the newest Android devices still don't support IPv6-only WiFi networks.

Source: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=32630

Answer (score 1):

It should be fully supported since Lollipop, except for DHCPv6 - see [the thread Matthew referred to](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=32630)

Answer (score -1):

Android 5.1.1 supports IPv6.
Here you han a screenshot of the console ‘netstat’ command (https://twitter.com/juan_domenech/status/732535218662412288).
You can also check this typing ‘what is my ip’ on Google and observing whether you have an IPv4 or an IPv6 coming back (only in IPv6 WiFi networks obviously).
Turns out that DHCPv6 is not necessary after all (SLAAC might be in place here).