# Are IPv6 Privacy Extensions supported and how can they be enabled/disabled?

Tags: security, networking, ipv6

I just read about a potential [privacy issue with IPv6 addresses on phones](http://www.h-online.com/security/news/item/IPv6-Smartphones-compromise-users-privacy-1169708.html). While the article mainly talks about Apple devices, Android *is* mentioned so I wonder:

Does Android support IPv6 privacy extensions and how can they be enabled/disabled?

According to [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/3718/2139) question, Android currently has *partial* support for IPv6.

Comment: Interesting question.  I'm wondering how the problem noted in the article is actually a real concern, though.

Comment: @MatthewRead When the EUI-64 address is used, the IPv6 address becomes (in theory) unique to the device. It identifies the device and possibly the manufacturer (of the NIC, at least). Though, so does the User-Agent string, and nobody cares much about those because they don't necessarily _uniquely_ identify the device.

Answer (score 2):

If your device is rooted go to the terminal after each boot and enter

`sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.default.use_tempaddr=2

sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.use_tempaddr=2`

For automatic activation you could also add these lines to /etc/sysctl.conf

`net.ipv6.conf.all.use_tempaddr = 2

net.ipv6.conf.default.use_tempaddr = 2`

Comment: Isn't there an app for that?

Comment: Not yet. ;-)
Seriously I don't think this is worth an app. it is merly a setting that should be configurable in the Wireless settings window.