# Android won't query DNS server for IPv6 addresses, why?

Tags: dns, ipv6

I have a weird issue; for a single connect request to a server that has a single AAAA record my device runs two A queries instead and fails to connect.

My setup is as follows:

- LAN (a regular router) without IPv6 connectivity
- Android 10 with only WiFi connectivity, having one `fe80:` and two `fd14:` addresses
- Debian box, wired, running `dnsmasq`, acting as the DNS server for all devices
- `dnsmasq` will reply that website `foo.com` has an IPv6 of the Debian box, and no IPv4

I can:

- Connect from my phone to the Debian box using literal IPv6 address
- Connect from other devices to `foo.com`
- Connect to `foo.com` from JuiceSSH
- Do `ping6 foo.com` successfully in Termux on the phone

What I can't do, I can't connect from my phone to the Debian box via `foo.com` using regular apps such as Chrome, or my own app. JuiceSSH is the weird exception. I tried making a new app, adding INTERNET permission and this bit of code only:

```
thread {
    Socket("foo.com", 9000)
}
```

This works consistently with the apps such as Chrome in that it doesn't connect and—from what I see in dsmasq logs—performs two A queries (both with `NODATA-IPv4` response). It never performs an AAAA query. `Inet*Address.getAllByName()` behaves in a similar way. I tested with another device running Android 6, same outcome.

What's going on here?

Comment: I'm not an expert in networking, but Android doesn't fully support IPv6, check the status on the related question: [Does Android have support for IPv6?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/3718/44325)

Comment: @AndrewT. Some applications do resolve IPv6 on my device; also my app can connect to IPv6 for other users. So I keep thinking that something is weird about my setup

Comment: I think that I stumbled upon a similar problem. Mine happens while using a IPv6 VPN, but probably the symptoms and result are all the same. I asked it here: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/244749/366910 Were you able to fix your problem or improve something on your end?

Comment: @MariusSiuram I weren't, sorry. I decided to stick with IPv4 in the end, oh well.