# Convince android to use AAAA records when VPN has IPv6 but main connectivity doesn't

Tags: vpn, dns, ipv6

I have a VPN (WireGuard right now, but the same behaviour manifested with OpenVPN) that provides me with an IPv6 address. I can confirm that it is working because pings (both from the android terminal with `ping6` and to the android terminal from the other side of the VPN) work. This also confirms that the VPN is establishing the DNS server properly, as I am using an internal domain while pinging from Android.

However, the browser (both Chrome and Firefox) only work properly when the main connectivity has also IPv6 enabled. That means that if I am connected to a WiFi that provides IPv6 connectivity, then the VPN works properly. But if I am using mobile data (my ISP doesn't provide IPv6) or I am using a IPv6-less WiFi, then the browser doesn't work for IPv6-only URLs. The android terminal `ping6` command keeps working in all scenarios, meaning that the VPN is properly connected and working, but it's as if the browser/android machinery refuses to use AAAA records and the browser gives me an error.

Is that a known issue? I am using Android 11. Can I change something or force Android to believe that there is an IPv6 connection established? Is the browser's fault? Is the DNS resolver fault?

Edit: Forgot to mention: if I manually enter the IPv6 into the browser, it loads the web properly. So it seems that there is a DNS issue there, but the DNS is properly set up. So I assume that Android (or both browsers) are misjudging when to use AAAA records, hence the title of this question.

Answer (score 1):

Configure your VPN to route the entire IPv6 address space. The requirement is that you need a default route for IPv6 for chrome to consider AAAA.

I was having the exactly same problem on android 12 and my VPN was configured to only route a ULA /56. Setting a default route through the VPN should cause chrome to start resolving domains with AAAA.

The caveat is of course all IPv6 traffic now goes through the VPN even when your WiFi/Cellular has native IPv6. I guess I just have to prepare two profiles now.