# Find carrier allocated public IP address

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, samsung-galaxy-s-2, ip-address

Fido has a service where they allocate a public IP address for some fees. I have paid the fees and apparently they have allocated my phone a public IP address. In normal circumstances, I should be able to see the IP address in my device settings (status information), but it shows "IP address unavailable". Fido customer service is not able to help, saying that they only have instructions for the iPhone. For any other phone, I should contact the manufacturer.

Any idea how I could go about finding the public IP address that I am paying through my nose for?

Carrier: Fido in Canada.
Phone: Samsung Galaxy S2
OS: Android 4.0.3

Comment: Update: I used ADB shell and netcfg to see the ip address of the interfaces: rmnet0 UP       25.44.197.87/24. It keeps changing if I restart the phone. But that IP is not reachable at least using ping. It comes from department of defence in the UK!

Comment: That IP will likely be internal to the carrier's network, they regularly use reserved IPs in situations where it "doesn't matter".  You could try visiting ipchicken.com or a similar site from your phone.  If that gives you the address of the carrier's gateway rather than your allocated IP I would assume they've screwed it up.  You'd think they would know what it is since they've allocated it, even if it's dynamic.

Comment: Related: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3715/is-there-a-command-or-application-similar-to-ipconfig?rq=1

Comment: I wonder if public IP address means something different to these carriers. It's infuriating, I've been in touch with Fido, Rogers, Samsung and there is no one who even knows how IP addresses are allocated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So reproducing the solution here for posterity: Need to change the default apn to either publicip.apn or vpn.com. All the other settings remain the same as the original default apn (which is fido-core.appl1.apn). Restart the device and voila!, the phone has a public ip. It can be discovered using adb and netcfg. @MartinSchröder, thanks a lot for pointing out Network Info II tool, its quite useful. Only thing is, after tethering the device, it reports an IPV6 rndis ip as the "internal" ip of the device.

Answer (score 4):

You could always use the browser hit one of the many web pages that will tell you what your IP address is. [WhatsMyIp](http://www.whatsmyip.org/) being one such.

Comment: That was among the first things that I tried. The reported IP is Rogers gateway device.

Answer (score 1):

Typically your carrier will be using NAT so you will have either a private RFC1918 address or an already allocated public IP.

A free app like [Net Tools](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sanctuaire.netswisstool&hl=en) will tell you the IP assigned directly to your  phone, so can you have IP communications with your carrier. (Net Tools will use netcfg as you have).

If you go to whatismyip.com you will likely find a different IP though because your connection is behind a NAT device. This is why you can't "ping" your phones IP.

Answer (score 0):

Get [Network Info II](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=aws.apps.networkInfoIi). It also gives you the name of your gateway.

Comment: Yes, but I need to find my phone's IP not the gateway.

Comment: @CocoroCara: Try the app.

Answer (score 0):

This open-source app might fit your needs, called [External IP](http://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=org.kost.externalip&fdpage=3).

> This simple application will show your IP addresses(default local &
>   external).

Comment: Thanks for the link. The solution is to configure the correct APN to get the public ip. But I had to struggle to get this information out of Fido customer service.