# Can I use ADB without connecting over USB?

Tags: bluetooth, adb

Is there a way to use adb directly via bluetooth instead of always via usb?

--

Thanks for the adb wireless solutions below, but I am looking for something that works well on hotel or public wifi. Bluetooth short-range might be the only way to go about it.

Comment: I rewrote this so as not to be a development question (off-topic).

Answer (score 9):

Personally, I use [ADBWireless](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=siir.es.adbWireless) with my G1 on CM5 because I had problems with the USB driver working correctly between my computer and my G1.  However, I had problems with this app in CM4 (to test against Android 1.6) on my G1.

Note, however, that it connect to the device via ADB via wifi, not Bluetooth.

You'll pull up a command line on your computer and type `adb connect xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:5555` (x's being your ip address of the phone over wifi). You'll have to run this in the platform-tools directory of your Android SDK, or you need to add your Android SDK platform-tools directory to your global PATH variable so you can run adb from anywhere.

Your phone will show up as its `ip_address:port_number` in the list of devices to push your application to, just as if it was plugged in directly via usb.

Comment: AFAIK, debugging over WiFi is not secure, because Android device doesn't authenticate host, so anyone can break into WiFi network and mess with your phone.

Answer (score 4):

**Non-Rooted Solution:**

- Enable USB-debugging in the developer setting and connect your phone to your computer via USB.
- Run the adb command, `adb tcpip 5555` (Make sure port 5555 is not blocked by any firewall programs)
- [To get your Wi-Fi IP address assigned to your device](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/2988/27149),

  `adb shell` and then `netcfg` and run the adb command `adb connect <IP_ADDRESS>`.

  For example, `adb connect 192.168.1.133`
- Now you can disconnect the usb cable and run `adb shell`, `adb install`, or `adb push` commands via your Wi-Fi.
- Inorder to switch back to USB mode and disable the Wireless mode, run the following adb command.

  `adb usb`
- You can also simply reboot your phone to switch back to the USB mode.

**Rooted Solution:**

- Install [WiFi ADB](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ttxapps.wifiadb) and run adb commands wirelessly if your phone is rooted.
- This app requires Developer tools enabled and no need to use USB cable if you are rooted.

Comment: AFAIK, debugging over WiFi is not secure, because Android device doesn't authenticate host, so anyone can break into WiFi network and mess with your phone.

Comment: @SargeBorsch Check out this workaround if you are concerned about connecting you device and debugging via WiFi. http://stackoverflow.com/a/19485468/1793718

Comment: How do I connect my Android TV to my computer via USB? They have both female USB-A ports ;)

Answer (score 4):

**2020 Update: Android 11 enabled built in Wireless Debugging.**

Here's the [official announcement](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2020/04/android-11-developer-preview-3.html) on the feature, and here's a handy guide on how to [connect ADB without cables, without root](https://android.gadgethacks.com/how-to/set-up-wireless-debugging-android-11-send-adb-commands-without-usb-cable-0302898/).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Easy Remote and it works well on Android 2.3.7. You can find downloads and information [on its website](http://www.bartwell.ru/soft/android/easyremoteadb).