# Test app from Android Studio on device without USB

Tags: usb

I've started developing apps for Android with Android Studio. I've been using the emulator to test my app. Althrough it works fine, I want to test the app on my physical Android phone. The problem is, the USB connector of my phone is broken.

Is there a way to test my app without using USB, maybe with Wifi or Bluetooth?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you want to achieve here? If you're looking to debug the app on the actual device then *adb wireless* (search it) would help, but you can't set it up without USB connection or root access. However, you can at least see the logcat on the device by using some third-party apps. Transfer the app to the device using Airdroid or any app which acts as a server on the device. But the point remains, what do you want and what have you done to answer your own question?

Comment: Related questions [Link](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6949/can-i-use-adb-without-connecting-over-usb) ,  [Link 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14357705/adb-over-wireless) & [Link 3](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/62683/android-adb-connect-to-device-with-broken-usb-and-no-root)